# Building shared library depending on libcurl

Tags: c++, linux, curl, shared-libraries

Hello I'm a newbie in compiling shared libraries.

My shared library depends on curl, ssl and crypto.
I've compiled the libcurl and the output libraries are:
libcurl.so.4 --> libcurl.so.4.3.0
libcurl.so.4.3.0

and I've compiled my shared library using the following command:

`g++ -m32 -shared \
-o libtestshared.so.1 \
-fPIC ../build/*.o \
-lpthread \
../openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 \
../openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 \
../curl/lib/libcurl.so.4.3.0`

But when I figure out what are the libraries my library depends on, I found:

`ldd libtestshared.so.1`

```
linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0x00e2a000)

libpthread.so.0 => /lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00aec000)

libssl.so.1.0.0 => /home/usr1/openssl/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x0034c000)

libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /home/usr1/openssl/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x003a8000)

libcurl.so.4 => /home/usr1/curl/lib/libcurl.so.4 (0x001cf000)

libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00229000)

libm.so.6 => /lib/libm.so.6 (0x006be000)

libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00eaf000)

libc.so.6 => /lib/libc.so.6 (0x006e8000)

/lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0x0055e000)

libdl.so.2 => /lib/libdl.so.2 (0x001ba000)

librt.so.1 => /lib/librt.so.1 (0x00314000)
```

Why only libcurl is refereing to the symbolic link?

Comment: Do you have symbolic links for `libssl` and `libcrypto` in `/home/usr1/openssl/lib/`?

Comment: Yes, I have, but what I need is not to link my library with libcurl symbolic link

Comment: What is the problem in linking to symbolic link? I mean what is your usecase

Comment: The shared library soft links indicate version number dependencies. Apparently your linker decided that the "4" version is strong enough - you don't need the more detailed version numbers?

Comment: @Miline My usecase is to link only with this version 4.3.0 because anyone could change the symbolic link reference. May links it to the newest version.

Comment: @KlaasvanGend I need my compiler to ignore the symbolic or to be forced with the actual version

Comment: Why dont you just remove the symbolic links then? Just keep which you want.

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work, I removed the symbolic link and compiled my library but it still sees the symbolic one

Comment: run `ldconifig` after removing the symbolic link?